# Scale height of div with jquery - How will google react (SEO)?

Tags: javascript, seo

Suppose I have a big div including much text. I want to show my readers only the first few text-lines. So I thought about scaling down the height of the div with javascript/jquery and add a "Read more" button.
Like that:

```
 $('#content').height(20);
```

Here's a complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/zvQsX/1/

I guess google will index all the content, but will google interpret this as spam?

Thanks for your help!

Best

Andi

Comment: Why would Google interpret a styled element containing oh-so-valuable-text as spam?

Comment: Maybe spam is the wrong word. I meant: Is it possible, that google will penalize your rankings, because they think you want to hide content from the user? Or is the content that can't be seen directly, worth less?

Comment: @ZenMaster: Because Google considers that if you feed GoogleBot something else than what you give to your users, then you must be cheating to obtain a better place in the Search Engine Result Page than what deserves the content your really give to your users. I don't know if they use the word "spam" but that's how it is.

Comment: How would google decipher that the height is different? Would then any expandable content (and there is a looooot of it on the Web) consider spam?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think Google interprets a bit of CSS and display:none and simply would consider a hidden content as non-existent or at-least as less relevant than what you display directly.

Your technique is different and I honestly don't know how Google would interpret it. If we consider the law's intent, you are actually giving your users the whole thing (they can read it if they want and it's on the same page), and it shouldn't be considered as black hat thingy.

That said, why do you want to use scaling of div instead of display:none or text-indent:-9999px ?